# Works on Pycharm but nonexecutable (unable to find 'vosk')

Tags: python, pyqt5, vosk

[image: Error message that shows when I try to execute .exe built file]

I tried to make speech recognition program using vosk model

Everything worked on pycharm and I built exe file using command

```
pyinstaller -w -F --icon=vtt_Icon.ico -n "Video Searcher" main.py
```

However when I execute it, the message shows like the image above

(지정된 파일을 찾을 수 없습니다 means "Failed to open directory")

And the folder named **MEI2327722** only appears when I execute exe file
and disappears when close exe file.

Why this happens and how shoud I do?

[image]
This image is my project file view

Answer (score 0):

first find directory where folder named 'vosk' exist
and edit

```
datas=[]
```

to

```
datas=[('vosk_directory', './vosk')]
```

at .spec file

then re-build exe file by not using .py but .spec
for example

```
pyinstaller -F main.spec
```